# redirection issue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have done a redirection to `dashboard_path` after user signing in.. I believe that there should be an action called dashboard in that controller. But when I removed that dashboard action in the controller it still worked fine. How is it possible.? Please help. I am confused.

In the sessions controller

```
def create
  admin=Admin.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
  user=User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)

  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    redirect_to dashboard_path
  else
    redirect_to(admins_index_path(:current_admin=>admin))
  end
end
```

In the User controller (If I removed this action in user controller still it redirects to dashboard page.. how??)

```
def dashboard
end
```

routes.rb

```
match '/dashboard' => 'admins/users#dashboard'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called 'convention over configuration', and Rails have a lot of it. If you don't specify any `render` or `redirect_to` in the controller action, Rail's default behavior is to redirect to the view with the same name as the action.

You should read the [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) for more information on this subject (it's part of the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) and contains a lot of information on Rails behavior).